Unhandled Runtime Error, ChunksLoad Error in next js
I am making a webpage which makes the payment with stripe and then it redirects to the page through stripe.
Example
https://localhost:3000/payment      -> https://localhost:3000/limit-status?payment_intent=ABCD&client_secret=ABCD
but during loading this page, If I click on close icon of url bar, then it gives m error


Try the following:

Delete .next folder in the project root
Start your project again
Make force refresh in your browser to delete the cache

